# How to edit uploaded csv files using django?

Tags: python, django, database, csv

I want to know, how one can edit an uploaded CSV file to the database, using Django admin panel and then save the changes.

Details: So I have uploaded a csv file to the database and I want my users to go the Django admin panel, log in with their username and password and then edit the uploaded CSV file and then save the changes.

P.S: I am a beginner in Django so any help will be much much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you upload CSV to database? Is this the data mapped to tables in db or just a file stored in db?

Comment: Just a file stored in DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Django third party app called **django-import-export**.
Here is it's git link:
https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export

It comes very handy when importing/exporting csv, xls and many other formats in Admin Panel.

For example to add import/export option to a model after installing **django-import-export** in *admin.py* write the following:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    pass
```

To enable selective export option instead of exporting the whole model:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    pass
```

Comment: Yeah i will try this one!

Comment: U need to install django-import-export first

Comment: And yes also i have figured out a way to work that out so thank you very much bro!!

Answer (score 0):

Django admin (and django in general) does not provide any editing functionality for editing CSV files. Your only option is to let users download the uploaded file, change it and then upload it again in the place of the old one. There's also no third party tool to make this in the admin. You have write your own probably.

Comment: I think so by using the django-import-export it COULD work like said by @Sachive Paruchuri. I don't know really guess i would have to try it first.

Comment: Import-export lib will be fine, but it will depend on the Model, so you will have to define one so it fits your csv file structure. Good luck anyway :)